# regular expression: end of line in MS visual studio

Tags: c, regex, visual-studio

I am trying to do something relatively simple, but am being thwarted by Visual Studio's unique (to be kind) regular expression syntax.

Trying to replace the following at the end of a line:   0,0
with:    0,0,xyz

When I search:   0,0$
and use the replace:    0,0,xyz

it replaces the newline and puts the text on the next line.
I've tried several other variations, to no avail.

Comment: Aren't you just trying to append a string to another string? Is there a reason you need a regular expression for this? Also, which language is this? Or are you doing this in the IDE (like search and replace)?

Comment: `0,0$` and `0,0,xyz` works perfectly for me in "Find and Replace" dialog of VS 2010. If you need to insert an additional newline in the replacement string, you can use `\n`, like this: `0,0,xyz\n`

Comment: The language is c.   I am trying to append one string to another, but the pattern appears multiple places in the line, and I'm trying to replace only the one at the end of the line

Comment: Can you show us your code, as this is C.

Comment: Solved:  I was using the Find/Replace in the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools package.  No idea why this behaves differently, but when I went back to the native Find/Replace it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was using the Find/Replace in the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools package. No idea why this behaves differently, but when I went back to the native Find/Replace it works.

Comment: Where did you find the find/Replace native tool? Could you please elaborate on your answer?